# how to validate form(do not take null value) on sapui5

Tags: sapui5

my form

```
 var oSimpleForm = new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm({
                maxContainerCols: 2,
                content:[
                    new sap.ui.core.Title({text:"Employee"}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Emp No",required:true}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"",}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"First Name"}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"",required: true}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Last Name"}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"",required: true}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Street"}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"",required: true}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"Country"}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"",required: true}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"City"}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"",required: true})

                ]

            });                
            oCreateDialog.addContent(oSimpleForm);
            oCreateDialog.addButton(
                new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                    text: "Submit", 
                    press: function() {
                    //validate input data not null
                     }
                })
            );
```

This is simple form, to take some input data.My question is -- On click of submit button how can i validate input data or no data field should be empty at the time of submitting...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function() {
  // get the content (as array)
  var content = oSimpleForm.getContent();
  // check every single control
  for (var i in content) {
    var control = content[i];
    // check control only if it has the function getValue
    // a rather primitive way to filter the TextFields
    if(control.getValue) {
      // check the value on empty text
      if(control.getValue() === "") {
        // do whatever you want to show the user he has to provide more input
        alert("empty value found");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to only alert once:

```js
function() {
  var content = oSimpleForm.getContent();
  // assume all controls are valid, if one is invalid this flag is set to false
  var allValid = true;
  for (var i in content) {
    var control = content[i];
    // in case one control was invalid the variable allValid has been set to false
    if(allValid && control.getValue && control.getValue() === "") {
      allValid = false;
      // stop the for-loop
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!allValid) {
    alert("empty value found");
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your code... it really helped.. but the alert msg is keep poping out for no of empty fields.. how to make it pop only once( irrelevant of no of empty field)

Comment: that alert is only an example of an action to to. if you want to use it i'll add a second version that should only alert once.